# Select rows with different id but same values

Tags: postgresql

I would like to find all records with the same values but different id's.

Here is the data I currently have:

```
+------+------+
|id    |userid|
+------+------+
|1     | 5    |
+------+------+
|1     | 8    |
+------+------+
|2     | 10   |
+------+------+
|2     | 12   |
+------+------+
|3     | 5    |
+------+------+
|3     | 8    |
+------+------+
|4     | 8    |
+------+------+
|4     | 13   |
+------+------+
```

id 1 has the same exact userid values as id 3. I want to see all the tables that have the same userid values.

Here is the results I would like it to return:

```
+------+------+
|id    |userid|
+------+------+
|1     | 5    |
+------+------+
|1     | 8    |
+------+------+
|3     | 5    |
+------+------+
|3     | 8    |
+------+------+
```

Im using Postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to use aggregation and `array_agg()` to get an array of the user IDs per ID. You can then inner join back to the original table and use `EXISTS` to filter for different IDs that share the same array, i.e. user ID. For convenience the derived table containing the aggregation can be put in a CTE.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT t.id,
       array_agg(t.userid ORDER BY t.userid) userids
       FROM elbat t
       GROUP BY id
)
SELECT t1.*
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN cte c1
                       ON c1.id = t1.id
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM cte c2
                            WHERE c2.id <> c1.id
                                  AND c2.userids = c1.userids);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7d58f144de74fe19a323238aa290113d)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to filter the userid that appears more than one time:

```
select
userid
from table
group by userid
having count(1) > 1
```

This will return:

```
userid
------
     5
     8
```

Now using this as a subquery you can select the complete result you want:

```
select 
*
from table
where userid in (
  select
  userid
  from table
  group by userid
  having count(1) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id,
       userid,
       string_agg(userid::text, ',') OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                           ORDER BY userid 
                                           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                                    AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) total
FROM test
)
SELECT DISTINCT cte1.id, cte1.userid /* , cte1.total */
FROM cte cte1, cte cte2
WHERE cte1.total = cte2.total
  AND cte1.id != cte2.id
ORDER BY cte1.id, cte1.userid
```